# Force Mac OSX to restart instead of waking up

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

Whenever I put my MacBook to sleep and then let it run out of battery, it takes a very long time (5-10 minutes) to wake up and let me log in, and then it runs slowly for 15-30 minutes after that. This is slow enough that in many cases, I would rather just restart my computer and pull up the work I was doing beforehand by myself.

When I open my laptop's lid to wake it up from sleep, is there anything I can do to interrupt the wakeup process and immediately have my computer restart instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can hold down the power button for 10 seconds, wait a couple seconds, then press the power button again and it should boot.  However, if the computer battery is still dead, it may take a few minutes before the battery will charge up enough before the computer will boot.

So, once the battery has had enough time to charge up from dead (~5-10%) it should allow you to restart it.